# Can't access my linked list methods and can't iterate trough it

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

So im following along this playlist about data structures and in this video to conclude the linked list part, the professor explain we need an inner class called IteratorHelper.

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bx0ebSGUKto&list=PLpPXw4zFa0uKKhaSz87IowJnOTzh9tiBk&index=21

This is the code in my github with the linked list implementation and the main class called tester:
https://github.com/Ghevi/Algos-DataStructures/tree/master/src/com/ghevi/ads/linkedlists

The problem is that the tester class can't compile. If I instantiate the linked list as an ListIterator i can't access its methods. I also can't iterate trough it regardless of having the IteratorHelper inner class. 
In the video he writes "implements ListI<>" is just a shorter version for ListIterator<>?
Sorry im just a beginner.

```
package com.ghevi.ads.linkedlists;

import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ListIterator<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        int n = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            list.addFirstWithTail(i);


        int removedFirst = list.removeFirst();
        int removedLast = list.removeLast();

        for(int x : list){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you tell us what you mean by "can't compile"? What's your error message?

Comment: sorry my bad, i mean that list.addFirstWithTail(i) cannot be resolved, the methods i wrote in the LinkedList class cannot be accessible if i write list.   

And also at the end , i cant iterate with the for each loop, it s say it cant be applied to type

If i declare list as a LinkedList instead of ListIterator i can access those methods but still cannot use the for each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video is not very clear, but basically `LinkedList` should implement `Iterable`, not `ListIterator`. `IteratorHelper` should implement `ListIterator` (see 4:20 timestamp).

Here's the fixed code:

```
package linkedlists;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

// Notes at Notes/Singly LinkedList.txt

public class LinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new IteratorHelper();
    }

    class IteratorHelper implements ListIterator<E>{

        Node<E> index;

        public IteratorHelper(){
            index = head;
        }

        // Return true if there is an element to return at the pointer
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (index != null);
        }

        // Return the element where the pointer is and mover the pointer to the next element
        @Override
        public E next() {
            if(!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();

            E val = index.data;
            index = index.next;

            return val;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public E previous() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int nextIndex() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int previousIndex() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {

        }

        @Override
        public void set(E e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void add(E e) {

        }

        /* For version older than java 1.8
        public void remove(){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void forEachRemaining(){};
        */

    } // inner class (can only be accessed by the outer class)

    class Node<E> {

        E data;
        Node<E> next;

        public Node(E obj){
            data = obj;
            next = null;
        }
    } // inner class (can only be accessed by the outer class)

    private Node<E> head;
    private Node<E> tail;
    private int currentSize;

    public LinkedList(){
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        currentSize = 0;
    }

    public void addFirst(E obj){
        Node<E> node = new Node<E>(obj);

        // The order of these 2 lines is fundamental
        node.next = head;
        head = node;

        currentSize++;
    }

    public void addFirstWithTail(E obj){
        Node<E> node = new Node<E>(obj);

        if(head == null){
            head = tail = node;
            return;
        }

        // The order of these 2 lines is fundamental
        node.next = head;
        head = node;

        currentSize++;
    }

    // O(n)
    public void slowAddLast(E obj){
        Node<E> node = new Node<E>(obj);

        if(head == null){
            head = tail = node;
            currentSize++;
            return;
        }

        Node<E> tmp = head;

        while(tmp.next != null){
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }

        tmp.next = node;
        currentSize++;
    }

    // O(1)
    public void fasterAddLast(E obj){
        Node<E> node = new Node<E>(obj);

        if(head == null){
            head = tail = node;
            currentSize++;
            return;
        }

        tail.next = node;
        tail = node;

        currentSize++;
    }

    public E removeFirst(){

        if(head == null){
            return null;
        }

        E tmp = head.data;

        if(head == tail){
            head = tail = null;
        } else {
            head = head.next;
        }

        currentSize--;
        return tmp;
    }

    public E removeLast(){
        if(head == null){
            return null;
        }

        if(head == tail){
            return removeFirst();
        }

        Node<E> current = head; // Can also write Node<E> current = head, previous = null;
        Node<E> previous = null;

        while(current != tail){
            // The order is crucial
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        previous.next = null;
        tail = previous;
        currentSize--;

        return current.data;
    }


    public E findAndRemove(E obj){
        Node<E> current = head, previous = null;

        // In an empty list current = null so we skip to the last line
        while(current != null){
            if(((Comparable<E>)obj).compareTo(current.data) == 0){

                // Beginning or single element
                if(current == head)
                    return removeFirst();

                // Ending of the list
                if(current == tail)
                    return removeLast();

                currentSize--;

                // Removing the reference to the node to delete
                previous.next = current.next;

                return current.data;
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        // Node not found
        return null;
    }

    public boolean contains(E obj){
        Node<E> current = head;

        while(current != null) {
            if(((Comparable<E>) obj).compareTo(current.data) == 0)
                return true;

            current = current.next;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public E peekFirst(){
        if(head == null)
            return null;

        return head.data;
    }

    public E peekLast(){
        if(tail == null)
            return null;

        return tail.data;
    }



}
```

The interface methods `hasPrevious, next,` etc... have been moved into the `IteratorHelper` class which implements `Iterator`. The `LinkedList` class has an `iterator()` method because it implements `Iterable`. Now you can instantiate a `LinkedList` object and iterate over it in a for-loop:

```
package linkedlists;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        int n = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            list.addFirstWithTail(i);


        int removedFirst = list.removeFirst();
        int removedLast = list.removeLast();

        for(int x : list){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a handy chart to remind you which class should have which functions:
[image]

[More on Iterable vs Iterator](https://stackabuse.com/java-iterable-interface-iterator-listiterator-and-spliterator/)

Comment: Thank you a lot it works properly now. I'm gonna mark your answer as correct.

If you dont mind i have one more question: cant i change the signature of the variable list in
```LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();``` 
to something like 
```Iterable<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();``` 
so using polymorphism? He mentions this aswell in the video but it doesnt seems to work unlike something like we do in 
```List<> myList = new ArrayList<>();``` ?

Comment: You can make "list" of type Iterable<Integer>, but then if you want to use functions specific to LinkedList (addFirstWithTail(), etc...), which are not defined for Iterable, you need to cast "list" to type LinkedList, for example:
((LinkedList<Integer>) list).addFirstWithTail(i);